# .Net Core 7 System.CommandLine.RootCommand.SetHandler fileinfo ReadAllBytesAsync

Tags: c#, .net-core, fileinfo

Is there any way to read from `FileInfo` to `byte[]`?

```
   rootCommand.SetHandler(async (file) =>
        {
            if (!file.Exists)
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Invalid input file: {file.Name}");
            using var package = new ExcelPackage(file);
            ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
            ExcelWorksheets worksheets = package.Workbook.Worksheets;
            if (!worksheets.Any())
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Invalid empty {file.Name}");
            byte[] data = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(file); <= XXX here. How to read from FileInfo to byte[]?
```

Comment: `byte[] data = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(file.FullName)` didn't work?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.exists?view=net-7.0 does not have `FullName`?

Comment: Yes, it has, but it belongs to the parent type which is : `FileSystemInfo`, `FileInfo` derives from it.

Comment: I just tried. `FileInfo.Name` also works.